# Rooting Samsung Galaxy A8 tablet (SM-x200)

Tags: samsung, rooting, tablet

My device is a Samsung Galaxy A8 tablet (SM-x200) running Android 13. I need to root my device to perform certain actions (delete app data) through MacroDroid. I have a MacBook and no access to a PC.

I have read the XDA Dev threads, etc. but there are so many different files and different downloads and methods.

I am essentially asking if anyone here has the time and willingness to spell it all out for me and tell me exactly which files to download, and what to do with them.

Answer (score 0):

This tablet is Galaxy Tab А8 10.5 Wi-Fi SM-X200 and it has a unisoc processor. Try [this tool](https://github.com/zhuofan-16/Spectrum_UnlockBL_Tool) for unisoc devices. It should work with unisoc chips.

Clone the repository using `git clone` then change your directory to the cloned repository using `cd`

If you already enabled OEM unlocking on your developer options, Boot your device to fastboot mode using `adb reboot bootloader` then try `fastboot devices` if it can detect it. Here's the steps you will do in order:

Open cmd/terminal and navigate to the folder
execute `fastboot oem get_identifier_token` first to get identifier token

`./unlockbl.sh IDENTIFIER_TOKEN sign.pem signature.bin` to create the unlock file

`fastboot flashing unlock_bootloader signature.bin` to unlock the bootloader

Tell me if it works on MAC system plssss :)

Answer (score 0):

Rooting an android phone with a computer is mostly done by a Windows PC. But if you don't have access to a PC, you can root directly by your phone using some rooting apps.

By installing and running one of these apps such as Kingroot, it will start rooting and restarting until it has been rooted.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).